# Why my repeated solr query has different qtime?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a solr cloud setup, I fire a simple query in a loop. The number and type of documents and query never changes but the qtime and corresponding request time varies from 6 ms to 1000+ ms in the same loop. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of caching. When you start the service not all kind of [caches](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#Types_of_Caches_and_Example_Configuration) will be loaded into the memory(which is  dependent on auto warmup).

The query time is also dependent on the load on the server machine. If GC is running on the service because of other activities, then the queryTime again varies.

Comment: I am a solr n00b but looking at solr web dashboard I can see GC runs very frequently. Is this something that I should be worried?

Comment: There are again [3 types](https://plumbr.eu/blog/garbage-collection/minor-gc-vs-major-gc-vs-full-gc) of GC cycles, which again each of them can be tuned by multiple [collector](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#available_collectors) methods. This is also dependent on how much memory left in the machine apart from the heap(index in mmap). This well explained in [this](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems) article.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I read GC logs and I can see young gen GC is taking .2 to .3 seconds. I am not a Java guy but I guess JVM tuning is required.